# How to include a public accessible function in this jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am looking for a way to include a public accessible function in a plugin, but I am still learning jQuery/javascript so I cant get it to work proper. I want to access some code in the plugin, in this example the function called someFunc. So how should I do this, whats the best way?

It should look something like this $.pluggg.validation().

// my plugin wrapper

```
    ;(function($, window, document, undefined){
        $.fn.pluggg = function(options) { 

            options = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluggg.options, options);    

                return this.each(function() {  

                    var obj = $(this);

                    function someFunc(){
                        alert(options.label);
                    }

                });

            };

            $.fn.pluggg.options = {
                label: 'yeahhhhh'
            };

    })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: What are the odds of someone redifining the window or document ?

Comment: The [jQuery Plugin Authoring Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods) might just have the answer for you.

Comment: `someFunc` is scoped inside the `.each` function callback scope, you will have to move it to a different scope if you want to access it from the jQuery context.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - even if it was moved outside the each function, it would be in the plugins scope and not a "public" function accessible outside the plugin scope. The way to go is usually to pass some parameter to the plugin function.

Comment: @adeneo I'm aware of that. It'd be easier to propose a proper answer if OP specified what's the expected behavior from calling that function, that's either a getter, setter or both.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Yes, I knew you where aware of that, and in the question it pretty much says "It should look something like this $.pluggg.validation().", now that's dot notation (an object starting with $) and maybe just using an object literal instead of $.fn would be better? Who knows, it's just to vague!